# SCBCD MOCK EXAM

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

Why is the answer to the following question B?

In my view the answer should be C.

The developer has defined the following entity class office:

```
@Entity
Public class Office {

  @Id
  Private int Id;
  Private String name;
  @OneToMany
  Private List<Rooms> rooms;
}
```

Which of the following attributes will be in the corresponding generated static metamodel class for the 'rooms' field?

- A. Public static volatile CollectionAttribute rooms;
- B. Public static volatile ListAttribute <Room> rooms; **Actual answer**
- C. Public static volatile ListAttribute <Office, Room> rooms; **My Choice - Wrong**
- D. Public static volatile SingleAttribute rooms;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no correct answer to this question. Reason being that following mapping is invalid:

@OneToMany
Private List rooms;

It is invalid because collection have to

1. be parameterized type or
2. it needs targetEntity attribute.

This is documented for example in API of [@OneToMany](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#targetEntity%28%29). If we assume that mappings is instead

```
@OneToMany
Private List<Room> rooms;
```

or

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=somepackage.Room.class)
Private List<Room> rooms;
```

Then correct answer is C (assuming that `Public` instead `public` is typo). That is correct answer, because it is defined in JPA 2.0 specification as follows:

> • For every persistent collection-valued attribute z declared by class
>   X, where the element type of z is Z, the metamodel class must contain
>   a declaration as follows:
>
> ...
>     • if the collection type of z is
>        java.util.List, then `public static volatile ListAttribute<X, Z> z;`

And following these rules leaves us with:

```
public static volatile ListAttribute <Office, Room> rooms;
```